# Publish Input and Output Json to cloudwatch from Step Function States

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

Is it possible to publish the input and output json to each state in the State diagram of the step function to cloudwatch or something else directly? i.e. without using any lambda or anything?

Answer (score 0):

No CloudWatch can only provide state machine metrics. Input and output data traverse from start to end cannot be logged in to CloudWatch. It's only available in state machine execution history. AWS X-Ray might collect that data but I'm not sure about that.